# detect IsEncryptedString?

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0, system.security

How can we find the given string is encrypted or plain string?

to be honest thats all the question. For instance when I'm using dataprotection using DPAPI encryption, when the given string is already a encrypted string or may be before decrypt call, check if the given string is encrypted.

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=SQL2014;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=false;User Id=test;Password=test@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

Configuration for Data protection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var dataProtectionBuilder = services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName("TestDataProtection");
        dataProtectionBuilder.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"F:\Test Data\TestDPAPI"));
        //Configuration goes here
        dataProtectionBuilder.AddKeyManagementOptions(options =>
        {
            options.AutoGenerateKeys = true;
            options.NewKeyLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        });

        dataProtectionBuilder.ProtectKeysWithDpapi(true);//Scope to LocalMachine (default Scope.CurrentUser)
        dataProtectionBuilder.SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        dataProtectionBuilder.UseCryptographicAlgorithms(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.AuthenticatedEncryptionSettings
        {
            EncryptionAlgorithm = Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_GCM,
            ValidationAlgorithm = Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA512
        });
    }
```

Service will looks something like below

```
public class TestClass
    {
        IDataProtector dataProtector;
        public TestClass(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectorProvider)
        {
            this.dataProtector = dataProtectorProvider.CreateProtector("purpose");
        }

        private string Protect(string value)
        {
           return dataProtector.Protect(value);
        }
        private string UnProtect(string value)
        {           
            return IsProtected(value)? dataProtector.Unprotect(value):value;
        }
        private bool IsProtected(string value)
        {
            //TODO How can we find 
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would you *not* know? Does it come from a UI or an external system? How about some real code? Read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I thought the code is not necessary, because its a theoretical question. Lets say the configuration is coming from app settings connection string, in the application when we want to unprotect? user may or may not protected the string using known settings.

Comment: the assumption is the same parameters for encryption and decryption used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is indistinguishable from random bytes it is mist likely encrypted.
If there are patterns it is not encrypted.

Note that encrypted data may be encoded with with Base64, hex or another encoding, in that case it is necessary to decode before checking for randomness.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly am not familiar with DDAPI. A generic answer though since it's a generic question...

A string is just a piece of data. It's impossible to know if it's junk (encrypted) or not (decrypted) without knowing what to look for, that is, some kind of context or indicator you always know to look for. I would suggest that you encrypt your data (your string), then sign it. In 'isprotected', try to verify the signature. If it verifies you'll know you need to decrypt it and it's from a trustworthy source.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2008/06/25/how-to-sign-and-verify-the-signature-with-net-and-a-certificate-c/